# How to return a specific value in Excel based on multiple conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column in Excel with some which is called "Theme's" and they are standard. I have another work sheet with some random data also. Now I want to check whether a standard theme is in one of the two (thus only one column to check for the theme) columns and return the value next to it, whilst also filtering duplicate returned values.

Comment: Please add minimal sample data and the desired output.

Comment: Could you provide a sample here?